How to add a hyperlink to a rendered dataframe in Shiny for Python?
I am trying to add clickable hyperlink to a rendered dataframe in Shiny for Python. This is what I tried:
@render.data_frame
def output_df():
    IDs = input.IDs()
    filtered_df = df[df['ID'].isin(IDs)]
    filtered_df['Link'] = [f"""<td>   <a href="https://myserver.com/details?synonym={i}"> <div style="height:100%;width:100%"> {i} </div>   </a> </td>""" for i in filtered_df['Link']]
    return filtered_df

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know exactly how to do it?

You can use ui.HTML here:
from shiny import ui, render, App
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Tag": ["python", "py-shiny"]})

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.output_data_frame("my_df")
)

def server(input, output, session):
    @render.data_frame
    def my_df():
        df["Link"] = [
            ui.HTML(f"""<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{tag}'
                              target='_blank'>Link to SO {tag} questions</a>""")
            for tag in df["Tag"]
        ]
        return render.DataGrid(df)

app = App(app_ui, server)


